# Posting innerHTML using jQuery and DOM and getting btoa error

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a script that uses jQuery to take the entire html source of a page and then posts that data into a form where the POST script then uses DOMDocument to parse the html and gets the data that I'm looking for:

script.php

```
$data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
//find element ids and upload data to a db
```

This is the jQuery that is loaded on the source page:

```
jQuery(document.body).append("<iframe id='somenewtab' name='somenewtab' />");
jQuery(document.body).append("<form action='script.php' target='somenewtab' id='form_submit_data' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='hidden' name='data' id='submit_data'><input type='submit' value=' '></form>");
jQuery("#submit_data").val( btoa(document.body.innerHTML) );
jQuery("#form_submit_data").submit();
```

My issue is that in the console on the page that has the jQuery it sometimes gives me this error and the page stops and the data doesn't get posted to script.php:

```
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': 
The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
```

I cannot figure out what to do. Seems like some kind of encoding issue with the innerHTML. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa): _In most browsers, calling window.btoa() on a Unicode string will cause a Character Out Of Range exception._ The link shows a work-around.

Comment: This worked from your MDN link.    btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(document.body.innerHTML)));

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is some serious bad practice and could have some severe performance and security impacts.

Having said that, this could make it work -

```
btoa(encodeURI(document.body.innerHTML));
```

Comment: This answer didn't help. The page wouldn't even generate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an encoding issue. You have to fix the letters that are not in the `latin1` encoding by scaping them before running the `btoa` method. To do that, run this code:

```
base64 = btoa(str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
    return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
}));
```